# Matrix norm inequality proof: inverse of two p.s.d matrices sum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I wonder if the following matrix norm inequality holds:
Let $A$ and $B$ are both strictly symmetric positive definite matrix
$\|(A+B)^{-1}\|_2\leq \|A^{-1}\|_2$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder what you have attempted so far!

Comment: It appears to me that instinctively it is true, but I wonder if there is a rigorous  proof.

Comment: Which norm are you referring to as $\| . \|_2$?  Unfortunately, there are several different norms that this notation is used for.

Comment: What I'm getting at is that you will receive much more help (and avoid the closing of your question) if you demonstrate that you've tried something and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the euclidean norm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\|\cdot\|_2$ denotes the maximum singular value, then it can be proved as follows.

The inequality in the original problem is equivalent to showing
$$
\sigma_{\max}((A+B)^{-1})\le \sigma_{\max}(B^{-1}) \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{\sigma_{\min}(A+B)}\le \frac{1}{\sigma_{\min}(B)} \Leftrightarrow \sigma_{\min}(B)\le\sigma_{\min}(A+B)
$$
Since $A$ is PD, the last inequality above is easy to prove (consider the eigenvector for the minimum eigenvalue of $A+B$, then $\sigma_{\min}(A+B)=x^T(A+B)x\ge x^TBx\ge \sigma_{\min}(B))$.

Comment: Hi, I am wondering if this inequality still holds when $\|A\|$ refers to the Frobenius norm?