# Need to improve upper bound for $\| (uv^T + B)^{-1} \|$ (Sherman-Morrison formula)

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, inverse, upper-lower-bounds

I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ in the form $A = uv^T + B$, where $u,v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and $B \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$. I know $A$ is invertible and want to find an upper bound for the norm of its inverse using the vectors $u,v$ and the matrix $B$. More precisely, I want a bound for

$$\| A^{-1} \| = \| (uv^T + B)^{-1} \|,$$

where the norm can be the spectral or the Frobenius norm.

I'm trying to come up with something in terms of $u,v,B$, but with no success. Also, searching here I found some posts about sum of psd matrices (like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565035/matrix-norm-inequality-proof-inverse-of-two-p-s-d-matrices-sum) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018849/norm-of-inverse-of-sums-of-positive-definite-matrices)). This is not my case, unfortunately, but I still hope there is some idea out there to help me on this problem. The matrices $u^Tv$ and $B$ may be assumed to be invertible too.

**EDIT:** In fact, I was able to get a bound, it is close but still not exactly what I need. Using the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) we get
$$\|(uv^T + B)^{-1}\| = \left\|B^{-1} - \frac{B^{-1}uv^TB^{-1}}{1+v^TB^{-1}u}\right\| \leq \|B^{-1}\| + \left\|\frac{B^{-1}uv^TB^{-1}}{1+v^TB^{-1}u}\right\| \leq $$
$$\leq \|B^{-1}\| + \frac{\|B^{-1}\| \|u\| \|v^T\| \|B^{-1}\|}{|1+v^TB^{-1}u|} = \|B^{-1}\| \left( 1+ \frac{\|B^{-1}\| \|u\| \|v^T\|}{|1+v^TB^{-1}u|} \right).$$

In order to have something useful for my purposes I need throw away or bound the factor $v^TB^{-1}u$ in the denominator. Suppose we have the norms of $u,v,B,B^{-1}$. Is there a way to use this and make the factor $v^TB^{-1}u$ disappear (I don't want to compute the inverse, only the norm of the inverse is accessible).

Thank you.

Comment: Is $|1+v^TB^{-1} u|\geq 1-\|v\|\|B^{-1}\|u\|$ not enough?

Comment: Because this is relatively close to optimal. Indeed,  in the case where all vectors and matrices are just real numbers, the condition that the right hand side of the inequality I posted is larger than zero is equivalent to the condition that $|uv|\leq |B|$, which measures how far $|uv|$ is from canceling $ B $ and thus making the sum $ uv+B $ not invertible at all

Comment: @Bananach I think this is enough! Somehow I didn't realize this possibility. In this case, we will have something of the form $\|B^{-1}\| \left( 1 + \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} \right)$, what is nice. Do you mind in making your comment as answer? Any details you want to add are very welcome, thanks!

Comment: @Bananach I just realize I didn't understand how your right side equality is equivalent to $|uv| \leq |B|$ (I think it was supposed to be $|uv^T| < |B|$). I also didn't get the canceling you explained. Could you explain these points for me, please. Thank you.

Comment: I was refering to the situation where $u$, $v$ and $B$ are just scalars

Comment: @Bananach I see...so it is possible to have $1 - \|v\| \|B^{-1}\| \|u\| \leq 0$ in the general case. This is a problem.

Comment: Well of course it is possible. It is always possible. Even for the scalar setting. The matrix that you are looking at is not always invertible. My point was that using the inequality that I gave you is almost optimal in the sense that it will give you a non-trivial bound as long as the matrix is invertible at all

Comment: @Bananach But I am assuming everything is invertible if necessary. Being $uv^T + B$ and $B$ invertible does imply $1 - \|v\| \|B^{-1}\| \|u\| > 0$ ? What do I need to have this inequality? Thanks.

Comment: Well, I can't tell you much more. Was the inequality you got not enough for your purpose?

Comment: If $B$ is invertible, then $B+uv^\top$ is invertible iff $B^{-1}(B+uv^\top)=1+B^{-1}uv^\top$ is invertible. This, on its turn, is equivalent to $B^{-1}uv^\top$ not having $-1$ as an eigenvalue. Otherwise, one must have that $B^{-1}u$ is a corresponding eigenvector, in which case $v^\top B^{-1}u=-1$. The latter is thus a necessary and sufficient condition for $1+B^{-1}uv^\top$ to be non-invertible

Comment: If that's not the case, it's still perfectly possible to have $|v^\top B^{-1}u|$($\leq\|u\|\cdot\|B^{-1}\|\cdot\|v\|$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality) as large as one wants by rescaling $u$ or $v$ and still keep $1+B^{-1}uv^\top$ invertible.

Comment: If, however, $B^{-1}uv^\top$ has its largest eigenvalue equal to $1$, it's possible to have $\|u\|\cdot\|B^{-1}\|\cdot\|v\|=1$ and $1+B^{-1}uv^\top$ invertible - set e.g. $B=B^{-1}=1$ and $u=v$ with $\|u\|=\|v\|=1$, for in this case $B^{-1}uv^\top$ is a one-dimensional projection.